# Can't enable lazy loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is my `context`:

```
public class BanksContext : DbContext
{
    public BanksContext () : base("banks")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<History>()
           .HasRequired(t => t.Bankaccount)
           .WithMany(s => s.Histories)
           .HasForeignKey(s => s.IdBankAccount);

        modelBuilder.Entity<History>()
           .HasRequired(t => t.OperationType)
           .WithMany(s => s.Histories)
           .HasForeignKey(s => s.IdOperationType);

        modelBuilder.Entity<History>()
           .HasRequired(t => t.StatusType)
           .WithMany(s => s.Histories)
           .HasForeignKey(s => s.IdStatus);

        modelBuilder.Entity<BankAccounts>()
           .HasRequired(t => t.BankShort)
           .WithMany(s => s.BankAccounts)
           .HasForeignKey(s => s.Id_BankShort);

        modelBuilder.Entity<BankErrorLog>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.HistoryEntries)
            .WithMany(s => s.Errors)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.IdHistory);
    }

    public DbSet<BankAccounts> BankAccounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BankErrorLog> BankErrorLogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BankShortType> BankShortTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<History> Histories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OperationType> OperationTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StatusType> StatusTypes { get; set; }  
}
```

And thats my `BankAccount` model:

```
public class BankAccounts
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Iban { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<History> Histories { get; set; }
}
```

And now I want to retreive data:

```
private BanksContext _context = new BanksContext ();

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var firstBankAccount = _context.BankAccounts.FirstOrDefault();

    return View(bankAccounts);
}
```

The thing is I expected `firstBankAccount.Histories` to be `null`. For some reason its not, but it contains data of histories from database. It seems that lazy loading is not working properly. My question is - why?

Comment: How do you know lazy loading is not working? how are you proving this to yourself, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Did you check how many queries are fired to the database?. Use a sql profiler and check

Comment: @TheGeneral as I said "I expected `firstBankAccount.Histories` to be `null`"

Comment: But if you access it, it will load, so what is your definition of lazy loading? You need to research what this is because you are confused. Try http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_framework_lazy_loading.htm

Comment: @TheGeneral as far as I remember I had to use `Include` to have collection avaible. Without `include` collection should stay `null`.

Comment: Using `Include` means an _eager_ loading.